# How can I view a list of ALL documents in ALL Document Libraries in Sharepoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I would like to view a list of ALL documents in ALL Document Libraries in Sharepoint 2010. The reason I would like to do this is because I need to review the documents that have been changed in the past X days.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

GetSPReport.ps1:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ea 0

$X=10
$TimeFilter = (Get-Date).AddDays(-$X)
$SharepointUrl = http://www.sharepoint.com

"Name, Time, Size KB" | Out-file XDocList.csv 

$SPWeb = Get-SPWebApplication $SharepointUrl | Get-SPSite -Limit All | Get-SPWeb -Limit All 

% ($SPitem in $ SPWeb){% ($list in $ SPitem.Lists)  
   { 
     If ($list.BaseType -eq "DocumentLibrary")  
     {% ($item in $list.Items) 
       {   If ($item.URL.StartsWith("_")) {Break} 
            If ($item.URL.EndsWith(".aspx")) {Break} 
            If ($item.File.TimeCreated -ge $TimeFilter)  
        { 
 $result = """$($SPitem.URL)/$($item.URL)"", $($item.File.TimeCreated), $( $item.File.Length/1KB)"
 $result | Out-File XDocList.csv -Append
        } 
       } 
     } 
   } }
```

Comment: That's a neat script. Ideally I would like a web based solution (ie a page or view in the Sharepoint site).

Comment: http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/publish-a-workbook-to-a-sharepoint-site-HA010342809.aspx

Comment: Creating Silverlight Dashboards for SharePoint 2010 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh528517(v=office.14).aspx SharePoint 2010 Architectures Overview http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg552610(v=office.14).aspx , use - Excel Services, Visio  Services, Dashboards